# api bing maps - multi layer (line and pic) on one point

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, bing-api

I can't create multiple layers (images and lines) on the same coordinates.
Does anyone know how you can handle it?

example code:

```
for (; index_array < array_trip.length; index_array++) {
    latVal = array_trip[index_array].latitude;
    longVal = Microsoft.Maps.Location.normalizeLongitude(array_trip[index_array].longitude);
    map.setView({ center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latVal, longVal) });
    var pushpinOptions = { icon: path + 'car.png', width: 50, height: 50 };
    var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin({ latitude: latVal, longitude: longVal }, pushpinOptions);   
   map.entities.push(pushpin);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. When you open it for editing, there are hints on formatting on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't set the map view in an array. This will only cause issues. Secondly, ensure that the URL to the pushpin icon is correct. Perhaps try removing that option for now until you see the default pushpins displayed on the map, then try adding a custom icon.

If you want to separate your data into layers you should use EntityCollection's: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx

Here is a good blog post on layering: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/

Answer (score 0):

Use could initialize  [EntityCollection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx) to add multiple entities to the map at one time.

**Example**

```js
function GetMap() {

    var locations = [
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(60.173783, 24.941068),
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(59.338575, 18.065823),
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(59.922602, 10.749411),
        new Microsoft.Maps.Location(55.675817, 12.570452)
    ];

    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), { credentials: "Bing Maps Key" });

    //1. Add pushpins
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(locations[i]);
        // Add the pushpin
        map.entities.push(pin);
    }


    //2. Add a polyline
    var line = new Microsoft.Maps.Polyline(locations);
    map.entities.push(line);


    //3. Add a polygon 
    var polygoncolor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100, 100, 0, 100);
    var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(locations, { fillColor: polygoncolor, strokeColor: polygoncolor });
    map.entities.push(polygon);

    var bestview = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locations);
    map.setView({ bounds: bestview });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:600px; height:600px;"></div>
</body>
```